# System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "Task_Name" to type 'Integer' is not valid.' --- Xml Read Problem

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to grab a node from my xml and have it displayed into a textbox. However, the node I try to grab using

```
    Dim work As XmlNodeList = xmltest.SelectNodes("//Task")

    TextBox3.Text = work("Task_Name").InnerText
```

Comes up with the error --- "System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "Task_Name" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'"

I think it is because of the nodelist formatting, but i'm stuck with this problem.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or a different method to get it to work?

Comment: The error message suggests that you can index an XmlNodeList by ordinal only, not by name. You should turn Option Strict On and then issues like this will be caught at compile time instead of getting through to run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you had taken notice of what Intellisense was telling you when you wrote that code, you would have seen that the [`XmlNodeList.ItemOf` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist.itemof?view=netframework-4.8) (that's the default property of that type so that's what you're invoking when you index an instance directly) is not overloaded and only has a parameter of type `Integer`. If you want to use that type then you can only enumerate it (use a `For Each` loop) or index it by ordinal. If you want to be able index by name, you need to use a different type. As you have failed to provide the required FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, we can't tell you which of those is the best option.